# Multivariable Instantaneous rate of change clarification

Tags: calculus

When you are computing the instantaneous rate of change for $f(x,y)$ what do you take the derivative with respect to?

for example, for

$f(x,y) = (\operatorname{sin}(πx)\operatorname{cos}(πy), ye^{xy}, x^2+y^3)$

If I was to find the instantaneous rate of change for all 3 of these functions going through (1,2) with the velocity vector (3,-2) would I just take $\frac{d}{dx}$ of all of the functions at (3,-2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the change in $f$ as both $x$ and $y$ are changing, then you are going to need something that relates $x$ to $y.$  (a parametric curve perhaps, or a direction vector).

Without that, you can evaluate the sentivity of $f$ to changes in $x$ this is the partial derivative. $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$

And there is also a partial derivative with respect to $y,$ i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

If you have the partials, and a parametric curve then you can find the "total derivative"

$\frac {df}{dt} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} \frac {dx}{dt} + \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} \frac {dy}{dt}$  and these will correspond to the same derivative you would get if you subsituted $x(t),y(t)$ into your function.

Since $f$ is a vector, you will get a derivatives for each of the $\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$ components.

Comment: Thank you this helps a ton, the only thing I am not 100 percent sure on is how would i take the derivative with respect to t, for example the simple function $x^2 +y^3$ or $x^2(t)+y^3(t)$ what would dx/dt be?

Comment: @GMuf I am not following your question.  You are going to have to be more specific.  $x^2 + y^3$ doesn't mean anything by itself.  What is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, just for the equation you gave, $\frac {df}{dt} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} \frac {dx}{dt} + \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} \frac {dy}{dt}$ i know how to find $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$  for all of the 3 functions but not $\frac {dx}{dt}$ or $\frac {dy}{dt}$

Comment: Ok I added a velocity vector to the example, would this some how relate to $\frac {dy}{dt}$?

Comment: A velocity vector will indeed give you $(\frac{dx}{dt}, \frac {dy}{dt})$